# Problem with Jhipster Swagger-UI on backend only app

Tags: jhipster, swagger-ui

I just generated a backend only application using JHipster. But, could not access to the swagger UI. Only available swagger stuff is `v3/api-docs`

Checked dependencies and see below list.

```
springdoc-openapi-common-1.6.6.jar
springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core-1.6.6.jar
--
swagger-annotations-2.1.12.jar
swagger-core-2.1.12.jar
swagger-models-2.1.12.jar
```

these are all coming from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Above behavior is expected considering the note for the dependency

> This dependency is relevant if you want to generate the OpenAPI description without using the swagger-ui.

--

Then the question is; how come jhipster implementes `/admin/docs` to display the swagger UI.  I saw they include the swagger-ui distro in webapp folder.

Finally,
should I exclude above dependency and basically add below to get up the UI ? Or is there any other way to get UI up and running without changing the dependencies.

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.7</version>
   </dependency>
```